# Show the group name for boxplots in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
df_plots = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D'],\
                         'Value':[1,1.2,1.4,1.3,16,18,16,19,43,47,42,55,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6],
                         'Hit':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,1,0]})
```

And I want to show boxplots per each `Group`, and show the name of each Group per plot. Firstly I have tried this and works fine:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,6), sharey=False)
axs = axs.flatten()

for i, g in enumerate(df_plots[['Group','Value']].groupby('Group')):
    g[1].boxplot(ax=axs[i])
```

[image]

But when trying to show the group name per each boxplot, I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed. This is what I have tried so far:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,6), sharey=False)
axs = axs.flatten()

for i, g in enumerate(df_plots[['Group','Value']].groupby('Group')):
    g[1].boxplot(ax=axs[i])
    axs.flat[i].set_title('What goes here?')
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code snippet, here's what I would do:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,6), sharey=False)
axs = axs.flatten()

for i, g in enumerate(df_plots[['Group','Value']].groupby('Group')):
    g[1].boxplot(ax=axs[i])
    # g is a Tuple[<Group Name:str>, <Group Data:pd.DataFrame>] 
    axs.flat[i].set_title(g[0])
    
# Adjust padding to better accommodate box plot titles
plt.tight_layout()
```

[Resulting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXbmm.png)

Comment: That's it! Thank you for the answer @Sid Feygin